# Custom Sort Sections By Title String

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, grouping

I have an array of sections that are sorted by the Section models title. I would like to be able to custom sort these by the title. I.e choose which section has which `indexPath`.

Here is the struct:

```
fileprivate struct Section: Decodable, Hashable {
    let title: String
    let offers: [Offer]
}
```

Here is how I am grouping my data and putting them into sections:

```
func makeSection(offer: Offer) -> String {
    return offer.section
}

fileprivate func createSections(from offers: [Offer]) {
    let groups = Dictionary(grouping: offers) { (offer) in
        return makeSection(offer: offer)
    }
    self.sections = groups.map { (key, values) in
        return Section(title: key, offers: values)
    }
}
```

I know I can use a 'sort by' function however, this only sorts alphabetically. I was thinking I probably need a variable called index within my section struct?

Comment: You can write any function to `sort(by: )`.

Comment: So, basically you don't want to sort your `sections` based on the `title` alphabetically, but instead keep the order of the offers array that you already have?